# Copy to selected not available or doesn't work when highlighted

Tags: materials, modifiers

Having problems with copy to selected across the board. 
I'm trying to add a modifier to all selected objects. It's Greyed out.
They are meshes in their own collection, no other objects.

(skip to the end for main question)
Yesterday, I was selecting all objects and trying to add a material.
Copy to selected was available but wouldn't do anything.
I had to join every object and then separate (which isn't the worst),
but the objects were tied to shrink-wrap and probably had to use copy to selected to get them working again...

**How do I add a modifier to All selected objects**?

Comment: select all your object, then at last shift select the one with the modifier, then ctrl L > Modifiers?

Comment: I think I did that, but with Link Data from the search menu. You get a list of what you want to share, and then it works somehow. I will try with ctrl L! Thanks!!!

Comment: by the menu bar, it's Object > Make Links > Modifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select all your objects, then at last <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the one with the modifier, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Modifiers*. By the menu bar: *Object > Make Links > Modifiers*.